# How to change selected row's color without click

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, syncfusion

this is master-detatil grid.

after pageload, i did the mastergrid's first row select and show detail with out click.

now I do selected row's color change.

but i don't know how to change selected row's color.

below code is just example,

Assume that the first row of the master grid is selected(without click) and the color does not change.

thanks

'''C#'''

@page "/Ex/EXS/ExPage07"

@using Syncfusion.Blazor.Layouts

@code{

```
public aaa bbb { get; set; } = new();
```

}

```
<SplitterPanes>

    <SplitterPane Size="50%" Collapsible="true" CssClass="p-1">

        <ContentTemplate>

            <SfGrid ID="master" @onfocusin="@((e)=> bbb.grid_onfocusin(e,"master"))"

            DataSource="@Orders"

            GridLines="GridLine.Both" Width="100%"

            AllowSorting="false" AllowRowDragAndDrop="false" AllowGrouping="false">

                <GridColumns>

                    <GridColumn Field=@nameof(Order.OrderID) HeaderText="Order ID" TextAlign="TextAlign.Right" Width="120"></GridColumn>

                    <GridColumn Field=@nameof(Order.CustomerID) HeaderText="Customer Name" Width="150"></GridColumn>

                    <GridColumn Field=@nameof(Order.OrderDate) HeaderText=" Order Date" Format="d" Type="ColumnType.Date" TextAlign="TextAlign.Right" Width="130"></GridColumn>

                    <GridColumn Field=@nameof(Order.Freight) HeaderText="Freight" Format="C2" TextAlign="TextAlign.Right" Width="120"></GridColumn>

                </GridColumns>

            </SfGrid>

        </ContentTemplate>

    </SplitterPane>

    <SplitterPane Size="50%" Collapsible="true" CssClass="p-1">

        <ContentTemplate>

            <SfGrid ID="detail" @onfocusin="@((e)=> bbb.grid_onfocusin(e,"detail"))"

            DataSource="@Orders"

            GridLines="GridLine.Both" Width="100%"

            AllowSorting="false" AllowRowDragAndDrop="false" AllowGrouping="false">

                <GridColumns>

                    <GridColumn Field=@nameof(Order.OrderID) HeaderText="Order ID" TextAlign="TextAlign.Right" Width="120"></GridColumn>

                    <GridColumn Field=@nameof(Order.CustomerID) HeaderText="Customer Name" Width="150"></GridColumn>

                    <GridColumn Field=@nameof(Order.OrderDate) HeaderText=" Order Date" Format="d" Type="ColumnType.Date" TextAlign="TextAlign.Right" Width="130"></GridColumn>

                    <GridColumn Field=@nameof(Order.Freight) HeaderText="Freight" Format="C2" TextAlign="TextAlign.Right" Width="120"></GridColumn>

                </GridColumns>

            </SfGrid>

        </ContentTemplate>

    </SplitterPane>

</SplitterPanes>
```

@code {

```
public List<Order> Orders { get; set; }





public class aaa

{

    public aaa()

    {



    }



    public string focusGrid { get; set; } = "";



    public void grid_onfocusin(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.FocusEventArgs args, string name)

    {

        focusGrid = name;

        Console.WriteLine("focusGrid: " + focusGrid);

    }

}



protected override void OnInitialized()

{

    Orders = Enumerable.Range(1, 75).Select(x => new Order()

        {

            OrderID = 1000 + x,

            CustomerID = (new string[] { "ALFKI", "ANANTR", "ANTON", "BLONP", "BOLID" })[new Random().Next(5)],

            Freight = 2.1 * x,

            OrderDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-x),

        }).ToList();

}



public class Order

{

    public int? OrderID { get; set; }

    public string CustomerID { get; set; }

    public DateTime? OrderDate { get; set; }

    public double? Freight { get; set; }

}
```

}

'''

Answer (score 0):

The first record of the Master grid is not selected, hence its color is not changed. If you want to select a record in Grid without a click action, we suggest you achieve your requirement **SelectedRowIndex** property of Grid.

```
<ContentTemplate> 

    <SfGrid ID="master" @onfocusin="@((e)=> bbb.grid_onfocusin(e,"master"))" 

            DataSource="@Orders" SelectedRowIndex="0" 

            GridLines="GridLine.Both" Width="100%" 

            AllowSorting="false" AllowRowDragAndDrop="false" AllowGrouping="false"> 



    </SfGrid> 

</ContentTemplate>
```

We have a Master details sample in our online demo:

https://blazor.syncfusion.com/demos/datagrid/master-details?theme=material

Refer to our API documentation for your reference:

https://help.syncfusion.com/cr/blazor/Syncfusion.Blazor.Grids.SfGrid-1.html#Syncfusion_Blazor_Grids_SfGrid_1_SelectedRowIndex

Comment: SelectedRowIndex  is rendered only at the beginning. But I select several grids with combo box and look them up. Therefore, SelectedRowIndex is applied only at first and not after. Is there a way to render a SelectedRowIndex  every time the grid changes?